# How to concatenate with ## an item from a tuple without using a GLUE macro in the C preprocessor?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have a big code base that looks like this:

```
#define LIB_TUP_0_(A, B, C) A
#define LIB_TUP_0(TUP) LIB_TUP_0_ TUP
#define LIB_TUP_1_(A, B, C) B
#define LIB_TUP_1(TUP) LIB_TUP_1_ TUP
#define LIB_TUP_2_(A, B, C) C
#define LIB_TUP_2(TUP) LIB_TUP_2_ TUP

#define LIB_PARAM_PFX LIB_TUP_0
#define LIB_PARAM_T LIB_TUP_1
#define LIB_PARAM_NAME LIB_TUP_2

#define F(PARAM) \
    F_(LIB_PARAM_PFX(PARAM), LIB_PARAM_T(PARAM))

#define FS(PARAM) \
    FS_(LIB_PARAM_T(PARAM), LIB_PARAM_PFX(PARAM), LIB_PARAM_NAME(PARAM))

#define F_(PFX, T) \
    T PFX##_hello(T a);

#define FS_(T, PFX, NAME) \
    T PFX##_hello(T NAME) { return NAME; }
```

with a header definition `F` and a source definition `FS` for a lot of things.

The problem is that `PARAM` is a (new) standard way to provide parameters to the entire library and it needs to be a tuple of the form `(PFX, T, NAME)`. Some macros though only require certain parameters from this tuple or need to be passed in a different order.

The problem is that a lot of code doesn't use the 'glue' macro and I thought if there is a way to not have to use it...

This is an undesired, but working example:

```
#define LIB_GLUE(a, b) a##b

#define LIB_TUP_0_(A, B, C) A
#define LIB_TUP_0(TUP) LIB_TUP_0_ TUP
#define LIB_TUP_1_(A, B, C) B
#define LIB_TUP_1(TUP) LIB_TUP_1_ TUP
#define LIB_TUP_2_(A, B, C) C
#define LIB_TUP_2(TUP) LIB_TUP_2_ TUP

#define LIB_PARAM_PFX LIB_TUP_0
#define LIB_PARAM_T LIB_TUP_1
#define LIB_PARAM_NAME LIB_TUP_2

#define F(PARAM) \
    F_(LIB_PARAM_PFX(PARAM), LIB_PARAM_T(PARAM))

#define FS(PARAM) \
    FS_(LIB_PARAM_T(PARAM), LIB_PARAM_PFX(PARAM), LIB_PARAM_NAME(PARAM))

#define F_(PFX, T) \
    T LIB_GLUE(PFX, _hello)(T a);

#define FS_(T, PFX, NAME) \
    T LIB_GLUE(PFX, _hello)(T NAME) { return NAME; }

#define M (l, int, b)

F((l, int, ))
FS(M)
```

Undesired because I can't (maybe) afford to change every `PFX##_hello` to `LIB_GLUE(PFX, _hello)` in the entire code base. So I'm here asking if there is any way out of this without having massive refactoring issues.

Comment: If you need the code to use the `LIB_GLUE` macro for forwards extensibility, then you are going to have to hunt down the abuses (non-uses) of the macro and replace them.  With a bit of care, that should not be hard to automate.  I'd probably use Perl rather than `sed`, simply because the regular expressions will be less verbose.  You'd need to decide what to do about occurrences of `PFX##namee` in comments and string literals — you probably don't want those manipulated, but it isn't clearcut either way.

Comment: Are you sure you've identified your code fragments correctly?  Isn't the first one the problematic example with `PFX##_hello` while the second is in your desired style using `LIB_GLUE`?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I've mentioned `LIB_GLUE`  to make sure that I know of this possibility which I'm trying to avoid. So the desired result would be to have a solution that doesn't change `PFX##_hello` to avoid massive refactoring issues

Comment: I don't think I understand your problem then, but it is late at night here.  Good luck; I hope someone else can help you.